# Can i disabled swip to delete on some cell?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to make it so when the user swipes on a cell, the delete button does not show up in first cell only and enable to others cells

Comment: Post the relevant code or no one can help.

Comment: i have table view and i make  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
i need disable swipe in first cell to don`t show delete button

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code. Do not post your code in comments. And simply showing the declaration of one method is far from the relevant code.

Comment: @AhmedT3lab hi Ahmed, it seems like you are new here... usually you need to add some code when you post a question. I have posted my answer to the best of my understanding of your question. Don't forget to vote it up if it helps you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Implement this in where you have the tableview delegate and datasource implemented.

Comment: This may not be the proper answer. There may still be a need for the 1st cell to be editable, just not deletable.

Comment: @rmaddy he did not mention that he wants to edit the row as well.. so in his case this will work.

Comment: Yes, it may work. My point is that there is a more specific way to prevent deletion on a row. Without more info from the OP, the more specific approach may or may not be the better answer. Of course I am referring to the `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` method.